# DWM high CPU and GPU usage on lower end pc with D3D11

Tags: gpu, directx, directx-11

I'm developing an app that shares D3D11 texture between processes.
I'm developing on a medium-high end PC
Widows10, I7 10700F and Geforce RTX 2070 as my developing my machine here is what is reported in task manager for CPU and GPU USAGE.

```
APP_NAME |  CPU  | GPU  |
APP1.exe |  0.3% | 5%   |
APP2.exe |  0.7% | 4%   |
DWM      |  0.8% | 2.5% |
```

Now on a Windows11,, i3 1115g4 with integrated graphics task manager shows

```
APP_NAME |  CPU  |  GPU  |
APP1.exe |  9%   |  26%  |
APP2.exe |  8%   |  23%  |
DWM      |  28%  |  32%  |
System   |  10%  |  5%   |
```

This is a big difference  where the GPU is almost max out and CPU is really high which is expected given it only has 2 cores and total max of 4 threads and it has integrated graphics.

But why is DWM(Desktop Windows Manager) using so much CPU AND GPU(what is it doing with those resources) compared to the higher end PC.
Note the app works just fine with no hiccups just that app is still in early development so there will be more processing to be added on GPU and CPU and they are almost maxed out. I'm aware that my app specs require a higher PC but I wonder if there is something wrong with my app architecture

App architecture

App1 is a borderless window that covers one screen where I render to offscreen texture which is then rendered on its swapchain. This texture is created D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX and D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE.

App2 is another window in another screen that opens the shared texture handle and its composed with its scene and then presented on its swapchain.

Comment: What DWM do is explained here: https://jackmin.home.blog/2018/12/14/swapchains-present-and-present-latency/ so how much it works is very related to what you do. Difficult to say w/o a single piece of code as details matters. You should post a minimal reproducible code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier. Thanks for the article. I used presentmon and on my development machine it's using independent flip which bypasses dwm and the other pc it's not which is why dwm is really high. The question is why it's not using independent flip.